# Difference between training a Neural net inside if __name__ == '__main__' and without it

Tags: python

I would be grateful if someone could explain the difference between this code -

```
models = (encoder, decoder)
data = (x_test, y_test)

# VAE loss = mse_loss or xent_loss + kl_loss
reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs, outputs)
reconstruction_loss *= original_dim
kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
kl_loss *= -0.5
vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
vae.compile(optimizer='adam')

# train the autoencoder
vae.fit([x_train,y_train_1hot],
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_data=([x_test,y_test], None))
```

and this one -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    help_ = "Load h5 model trained weights"
    parser.add_argument("-w", "--weights", help=help_)
    help_ = "Use mse loss instead of binary cross entropy (default)"
    parser.add_argument("-m",
                        "--mse",
                        help=help_, action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args(args=[])
    models = (encoder, decoder)
    data = (x_test, y_test)

    # VAE loss = mse_loss or xent_loss + kl_loss
    if args.mse:
        reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs, outputs)
    else:
        reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(inputs,
                                                  outputs)

    reconstruction_loss *= original_dim
    kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
    kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
    kl_loss *= -0.5
    vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
    vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
    vae.compile(optimizer='adam')

    #if args.weights:
        #vae.load_weights(args.weights)
    #else:
        # train the autoencoder
    vae.fit([x_train,y_train_1hot],
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=([x_test,y_test_1hot], None))
        #vae.save_weights('vae_mlp_mnist.h5')
```

To my understanding both of them are the same, and I don't save the weights, and have commented the loading weights code, the validation loss for both comes out to be different, even though the reconstructions look the same. I do not understand why.

Comment: How do you run your code? The two versions will run differently **depending on the context**. If the file is named `training.py`, are you doing `python training` or are you doing `import training` in another file. Or are you doing something else?

Comment: Do you get the same results if you run the same code twice? Or does it have a random contribution?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am using Jupyter notebook, running it directly from the cell.

Comment: @mkrieger for the same code i get more or less the same result, around 20 units for the first one and around 100 for the second one.

Comment: I don't know anything about the Jupyter notebook runtime. My guess is that `if __name__ == '__main__':` doesn't make any sense in this context. I've only used that syntax when I run a file directly that I also want to import as a module into other python source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no difference if you run the second snippet with `python <yourmodule> --mse` (otherwise, your second snippet defaults to binary crossentropy, while your first snippet always uses mse).

Apart from that, the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard only changes the script's behavior such that included code is only executed when the module (file) is run. I.e., when importing your module, the first snippet would be executed, the second won't.

Comment: Oh I thought its defaulting to mse, but I realise I passed empty arguments, that could the reaon. I will check this and report back.

Comment: Hey you were correct, this is what was causing the idfference, sorry I  should have noticed this! MSE is giving around 20 units of validation error and Bxe around 100. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Overlooking such details is completely understandable :)